# Adding a vector of T/F to a list of vectors in R

Tags: r, list, function, loops, vector

I have a list of 2 vectors named `X`, `Y`. I want to add a new element called `H` to each of these 2 vectors which will show as `H = TRUE or FALSE`.

BUT, instead of showing `TRUE` or `FALSE` my output shows `1` and `0`. How can I show `TRUE` and `FALSE` in my current output?

```
H = c(T, F) # The element to be added

L <- list(X = c(K = 22, M = 39), Y = c(K = 54, M = 65)) # List to add to

Map(c, L, H = H) # My current solution

# Current OUTPUT:
# $X
#  K     M     H 
#  22   39     1   # instead of `TRUE`

# $Y
#  K     M     H 
# 54    65     0  # instead of `FALSE`
```

Comment: use `as.logical()` to get from 0/1 to FALSE/TRUE

Comment: what doesn't work about it? how did you write it? And maybe lists have some limitation that they all need to be the same type? I feel like I've read that somewhere... not sure though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can also convert the `vector` to `list` with `as.list` from the initial data and concatenate (`c`) as `vector` doesn't allow multiple `type`s

```
Map(c, lapply(L, as.list), H = H)
```

Comment: @rnorouzian Looks like it is answered

Comment: I hope you consider [**this question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58474393/subsetting-in-a-second-level-r-function)?

Comment: @rnorouzian I see an answer on that question

Comment: This one is getting a lot of upvotes as you can see, I don't see any troubles, but is there a solution?

Answer (score 3):

You have this problem because each element of the list is a vector, and a vector is a collection of elements of the same type. So it is impossible to get what you want using vectors, the booleans will always be converted to numeric as this is the types of the already existing vectors.

But you could use lists inside the list

```
L <- list(X = list(K = 22, M = 39), Y = list(K = 54, M = 65))
Map(c, L, H = H)
```