# Subsetting in a second level R function

Tags: r, list, function, dataframe, subset

Function `foo1` can subset a list by a requested variable (e.g., `by = type == 1`). Otherwise, `foo1` will simply output the inputted list itself.

For my purposes, I need to use `foo1` within a new function called `foo2`.

In my code below, **my desired output** is obtained like so: `foo2(data = D, by = G[[1]]) ; foo2(data = D, by = G[[2]]) ; foo2(data = D, by = G[[3]])`.

But, I wonder why when I loop over `G` using `lapply`, I get an error ***as shown below***?

```
foo1 <- function(data, by){

  L <- split(data, data$study.name) ; L[[1]] <- NULL

  if(!missing(by)){

   L <- lapply(L, function(x) do.call("subset", list(x, by)))
  }
 return(L)
}


foo2 <- function(data, by){

  eval(substitute(foo1(data = data, by = by)))
}

## EXAMPLE OF USE:
D <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/izeh/i/master/k.csv", h = T) ## Data

G <- lapply(unique(na.omit(D$type)), function(i) bquote(type == .(i)))# all levels of `type`

foo2(data = D, by = G[[1]]) # Works fine without `lapply` :-)

lapply(1:3, function(i) foo2(data = D, by = G[[i]])) # Doesn't work with `lapply`! :-(
# Error in do.call("subset", list(x, by)) : object 'i' not found
```

Comment: Why are you using `eval` + `substitute`? Also, consider a different variable name than `by` which is actually a function very similar to `split` (in fact `split` + `lapply`).

Comment: Also, this appears to be an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) where you ask help for a *y* solution but do not describe the larger *x* problem. Please give more background and explain your data input and desired results. Use of `eval`, `substitute`, `bquote` seems too much.

Comment: The `eval` inside the function is making it more prone to bugs without specifying the environment.

Comment: @akrun, went ahead and asked a related [question on this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58477309/a-replacement-for-subset-for-a-list-of-data-frames-in-r)?

Comment: @rnorouzian Yes, but that was based on the context.  As Parfait mentioned, it could be an XY problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `lapply`, here a `for` loop can be used

```
lst1 <- vector("list", length(G))
for(i in 1:3) lst1[[i]] <- foo2(data = D, by = G[[i]])
```

-checking

```
identical(lst1[[2]],  foo2(data = D, by = G[[2]]))
#[1] TRUE
identical(lst1[[3]],  foo2(data = D, by = G[[3]]))
#[1] TRUE
```

---

For the `lapply` part, there seems to be a conflict with `i` anonymous function which is also called in the `G`.  If we use a new variable say 'j'

```
lst2 <- lapply(1:3, function(j) foo1(data = D, by = G[[j]]))
```

should work

```
identical(lst2[[2]], lst1[[2]])
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Hi Arun, would [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58895249/changing-a-list-of-tables-to-a-data-frame-in-r) be of interest?

Answer (score 2):

Your `foo2` function tries to evaluate the expression

```
foo1(data = D, by = G[[i]])
```

but it doesn't have `i` available.  You need to evaluate `G[[i]]` in the anonymous function you're passing to `lapply` to get an expression defining the subset, and then evaluate that subset in `foo2`.  I recommend naming that function instead of using an anonymous one; it makes debugging a lot easier.

Here's some recoding that appears to work:

Redefine `foo2` to

```
foo2 <- function(data, by){
  by <- eval(by, envir = data)
  foo1(data = data, by = by)
}
```

and

```
foo3 <- function(i) {
    expr <- G[[i]]
    foo2(data = D, by = expr)
}
```

and then

```
lapply(1:3, foo3)
```

I'm not sure this does exactly what you want, but it should be close enough that you can fix it up.

Comment: @rnorouzian ... [why](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem#comment436926_66378) are you even calling `foo2`? Why not directly call `foo1`?

Comment: @Parfait, OP is saying s/he needs to use `foo1` indirectly. Please if you have an alternative solution, try to offer it. Apparently for OP, `foo1` is a nested function so s/he can't call it directly.