# Changing a list of tables to a data.frame in R

Tags: r, list, function, dataframe, frequency

Below, I first find if variables `X` and `Y` have a value that is repeated less than 4 times. I find and list these values in `low`.

I wonder, using BASE R, how can I transform `low` which is a list of `table`s to **my desired output** shown below?

***Note:*** The data below is toy, a functional answer is appreciated.

```
data <- data.frame(id = c(rep("AA",4), rep("BB",2), rep("CC",2)), X = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,3,3), 
                                                                  Y = c(9,9,9,7,6,6,6,6),
                                                                  Z = 1:8)
mods <- c("X","Y")
A <- setNames(lapply(seq_along(mods), function(i) table(data[[mods[i]]], dnn = NULL)), mods)

low <- setNames(lapply(seq_along(A), function(i) A[[i]][which(A[[i]] < 4)]), names(A))
```

**Desired output:**

```
data.frame(id = c("CC", "AA", "AA"), value = c(3, 7, 9), var.name = c("X", "Y", "Y"), occur = c(2, 1, 3))

#   id value var.name occur     # `value` comes from the `names(low[[i]])`# i = 1,2                                 
# 1 CC     3        X     2     # `occur` comes from `as.numeric(low[[i]])`
# 2 AA     7        Y     1
# 3 AA     9        Y     3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We split the subset of columns of 'data' with 'id', loop through the `list` with `lapply`, do an inner join with `merge` with the corresponding `stack`ed 'low' `list` of `table`s, `Filter` out the elements that are having number of rows 0 or `length` 0 to create 'lst1'.  From 'lst1', create additional columns from the inner and outer `names` with `Map` and `rbind` the elements

```
lst1 <- Filter(length, lapply(split(data[c('X', 'Y')], data$id), 
     function(dat) Filter(nrow, Map(merge, lapply(dat, 
        function(x) stack(table(x))), lapply(low, stack)))))

do.call(rbind, c(Map(cbind, id = names(lst1), lapply(lst1, 
   function(x) do.call(rbind, c(Map(cbind, x, var.name = names(x)),
          make.row.names = FALSE)))), make.row.names = FALSE))
#  id values ind var.name
#1 AA      1   7        Y
#2 AA      3   9        Y
#3 CC      2   3        X
```

Comment: @rnorouzian I added some explanations.  Hope it helps

Comment: @rnorouzian The reason is that it doesn't exist in the 'data' `subset(do.call(rbind, lapply(split(data[mods], data$study.name), function(dat) lapply(dat, function(x) stack(table(x)))$cf.type)), values == 2 & ind == 15)#
[1] values ind   
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)`. I used the data from the github link

Comment: @rnorouzian. It would be there, but what I meant is both `values ==2` and `ind == 15`.  Here, we split by 'id' and if you check the 'id's it is 26 and 35, so the frequency is only 1

Comment: @rnorouzian the reason is the frequency `subset(data, cf.type==99)$id
[1] 32 32` 2 of the same id, and it is matching `low$cf.type3
15 99 
 2  2 `

Comment: @rnorouzian Does it mean that you don't want to match the ones in 'low'?

Comment: @rnorouzian I think you are not understanding the issue.  If we do without matching, then you will get a lot of unnecessary unmatched values

Comment: @rnorouzian May be you need to merge only by 'ind' `lst1 <- Filter(length, lapply(split(data[mods], data$study.name), 
                               function(dat) Filter(nrow, Map(function(x, y) merge(x, y, by = "ind"), lapply(dat, 
                               function(x) stack(table(x))), lapply(low, stack)))))`

Comment: @rnorouzian Now, it does give that value as well

Comment: @rnorouzian That is the reason I said that your 'low' is not matching with the values in 'data'

Comment: @rnorouzian the `low` `cf.type` 99 is there in the output

Comment: @rnorouzian That is because the datasets we are merging both have 'values' column and we are not using that in the `by`

Comment: @rnorouzian I have a doubt, do you want this to be `split` by 'study.name'?  Also, regardng the new solution in the comments, you can remove one of the 'values' column  from the `merge` i.e. `merge(x, y[setdiff(names(y), "values")], by = "ind")`

Comment: @rnorouzian if you are not splitting `d1 <- do.call(rbind, c(Map(cbind, mod.names = mods, lapply(data[mods], function(x) stack(table(x)))), make.row.names = FALSE));d2 <- do.call(rbind, c(Map(cbind, mod.names = names(low), lapply(low, stack)), make.row.names = FALSE)); merge(d1, d2)`

Comment: @rnorouzian Yes.   It is from the data in your github using `data[mods]`

Comment: @rnorouzian Yes, in the previous code with `split`, we are looping one more nested `list` and have to take of `list` elementss with 0 length or number of rows with `Filter`.  I used `split` because in your earlier questions, you were doing that

Comment: @rnorouzian okay, glad to know that it i working.  I am going offline now

Comment: @rnorouzian You meant the use of `table` in `A` or the code in `lst` i.e. `stack(table(x))`.  It can be done in a faster option with packages, but I guess you want to do this in `base R` and that is the challenge.  Group by with `aggregate` is also an option, but that is also slow

Comment: @rnorouzian with `ave`, you would get the output with the same length, but I guess you need a summarise output and that is the reason I suggested `aggregate`.  Another faster option is `tabulate` but that won't give the labels

Comment: @rnorouzian  I answered it.  Please check

Answer (score 0):

```r
data <- data.frame(id = c(rep("AA",4), rep("BB",2), rep("CC",2)), X = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,3,3), 
                   Y = c(9,9,9,7,6,6,6,6),
                   Z = 1:8)

to_check <- setdiff(names(data), "id")
results <- vector(mode = "list", length = length(to_check))

# This function sorts the input and then uses the run-length
# encoding to determining values and their frequencies.
# table is an option, but the output is a lot harder
# to work with.
count_occurrences <- function(x, max_occurrences = 3L) {
  x <- sort(x)
  run_lengths <- rle(x)
  chosen <- which(run_lengths$lengths <= max_occurrences)
  if (length(chosen)) {
    values <- run_lengths[["values"]][chosen]
    occur <- run_lengths[["lengths"]][chosen]
  } else {
    values <- NA
    occur <- NA
  }
  data.frame(value = values, occur = occur)
}
for (k in seq_along(results)) {
# `tapply` will split the first vector based upon the values in `INDEX`
counts <- tapply(data[[to_check[k]]], 
                 INDEX = data$id,
                 FUN = count_occurrences,
                 max_occurrences = 3)
# Construct a data.frame of the results, repeating each name for the number
# of rows (values meeting the criterion) returned. 
# I've used `unlist(sapply(...)` for the other two because
# not every result in the list will have the same number of rows,
# and `vapply()` requires specifying the output type and shape.
results[[k]] <- data.frame(id = rep(names(counts), times = vapply(counts, nrow, integer(1L))),
                           value = unlist(sapply(counts, `[[`, "value",
                                          USE.NAMES = FALSE), use.names = FALSE),
                           occur = unlist(sapply(counts, `[[`, "occur",
                                          USE.NAMES = FALSE), use.names = FALSE))
results[[k]]["var.name"] <- to_check[k]
}
desired_result <- Reduce(rbind, results)
desired_result
#    id value occur var.name
# 1  AA    NA    NA        X
# 2  BB     1     2        X
# 3  CC     3     2        X
# 4  AA     7     1        Y
# 5  AA     9     3        Y
# 6  BB     6     2        Y
# 7  CC     6     2        Y
# 8  AA     1     1        Z
# 9  AA     2     1        Z
# 10 AA     3     1        Z
# 11 AA     4     1        Z
# 12 BB     5     1        Z
# 13 BB     6     1        Z
# 14 CC     7     1        Z
# 15 CC     8     1        Z
# subset as [!is.na(value)] to drop the ids with no values with frequencies less
# than `max_occurrence`
```